# How are subcollection reads counted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's take for example a database with a very simple structure. It has a **users** collection and a **messages** subcollection.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{id} {
      allow read, write: if true;
      match /messages/{id} {
        allow read, write: if true;
      }
    }
}
```

Let's assume that a target user has 100 messages.

1. How many reads will result from running this `db.collection('users').doc(targetUserId).get()`?
2. How many reads will result from running this `db.collection('users').doc(targetUserId).onSnapshot(callback)`?
3. Will the subsccription callback be called when a message is updated/deleted/added? How many reads will each invocation take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing):

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

So if you read one document, then you will be charged only for that one document read. If you read 100 documents, you will be charged for 100 documents read.

The same concept even if you are using `onSnapshot()`, if you are listening to the whole collection and you have an active `onSnapshot()` listener then yes, you will be charged for a document read operation each time a new document is added, changed, or deleted in the collection. If you are listening to a document you have an active `onSnapshot()`, then you will be charged for that one document read.

Comment: thank you, sir! One quick question though. Is my understanding correct that when I run `db.collection('users').doc(targetUserId).get()` I receive a user document with **messages** subcollection already populated. In other words, I don't need to make a separate read for **messages** and it all takes 1 read, right?

Comment: @manidos No, you will not receive the `messages` subcollection if you fetch one `user` document. **Queries in Firestore are shallow**. It means that you will have to query the subcollection (and to pay for those reads)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, I knew it was too good to be true. Phew, you saved me a lot of time. Thank you, sir!